How to parse API returned MultiForm data?
I inherited the code for a system that is still using asp.net 2.1.
One of the API that we are trying to connects to returns a multipart/form-data
--F77HAO7SxZC-Iy2+MKZ7pApb
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="labelMetadata"

{"labelAddress":{"streetAddress":"19914 S VIA BARON","secondaryAddress":"","city":"COMPTON","state":"CA","ZIPCode":"90220","ZIPPlus4":"6104","firstName":"MYFC","lastName":"SHIPPER NAME","firm":"MYFC SHIPPER COMPANY","ignoreBadAddress":false},"routingInformation":"420902206104","trackingNumber":"9200190109770100369558","postage":6.17,"extraServices":[{"name":"USPS Tracking","price":0.0,"SKU":"DXTU0EXXXCX0000"}],"zone":"01","commitment":{"name":"2 Days","scheduleDeliveryDate":"2024-09-19"},"weightUOM":"LB","weight":0.9625,"dimensionalWeight":0.0,"fees":[],"bannerText":"USPS TRACKING # USPS Ship","serviceTypeCode":"001","constructCode":"C01","SKU":"DUXP0XXXUC01159"}
--F77HAO7SxZC-Iy2+MKZ7pApb
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="labelImage.pdf"; name="labelImage"

JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrr...
--F77HAO7SxZC-Iy2+MKZ7pApb--

I have never handled this sort of response before.  What is the proper way to parse this?

The asp.net core contains the MultipartReader class which could read the multiple part response.
You could install it from this Nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
More details, you could refer to below example:
Please notice: you need replace the contentDisposition check condition according to your response, the example I have shared is using my test example response's value.
public class MultipartResponseHandler
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MultipartResponseHandler(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task HandleMultipartResponseAsync()
    {
        // Example API request (replace with your actual API)
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7072/Multipart");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "multipart/form-data")
        {
            // Extract boundary from the content type
            var boundary = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters
                                     .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "boundary")?.Value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(boundary))
                throw new InvalidDataException("Boundary not found in content type");

            // Get the response stream
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, stream);

            MultipartSection section;
            while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()) != null)
            {
                var contentDisposition = section.ContentDisposition;

                if (contentDisposition.Contains("form-data"))
                {
                    // Handle JSON part (labelMetadata)
                    if (contentDisposition.Contains("name=\"appsettings.json\""))
                    {
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(section.Body))
                        {
                            var json = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                          
                            // Process the label metadata object
                        }
                    }

                    // Handle PDF part (labelImage)
                    if (contentDisposition.Contains("name=\"111.txt\""))
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            await section.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                      
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
           
        }
    }
}

Usage:
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var multipartHandler = new MultipartResponseHandler(httpClient);

        await multipartHandler.HandleMultipartResponseAsync();

Result:

